# SQL to List Common Values of One Column Based on an Input List of Values From Another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have an ASP.NET application with SQL Server 2008 back end.
We have the following setup in our SpecimenEvents table:

```
EventID SpecimenID  EventType
      1        101        A       
      2        102        A
      3        103        A
      4        101        B
      5        103        B
      6        101        C
```

Given a list of SpecimenIDs as input -- how would you write a query to return just those EventType(s) COMMON to all SpecimenIDs in the input list?
For example:

a SpecimenID input list of (101,102,103) should return 'A'

a SpecimenID input list of (101) should return 'A','B','C'

a SpecimenID input list of (101,103) should return 'A', 'B' ...

Comment: Can they be returned as rows?

Comment: Yes, that would probably work

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct EventType
from (
    select EventType, count(distinct SpecimenID) as SpecimenCount
    from SpecimenEvents
    where SpecimenID in (101,103)
    group by EventType
    having count(distinct SpecimenID) = 2 -- Make this match the list length
) x
```

Comment: Extra `)` after `IN` and need a column name for `COUNT`, otherwise +1.

Comment: Thanks for your braintime, guys -- this might do it.  Is there a way to do this with SQL Server CTEs without having to input the length of the input list?

Comment: @user1132464 I'm pretty sure you can't do it without the length. I am reluctant to say "impossible", but I've never seen it done and I can't think how you could do it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with aggregated columns (try your code with `EventType + ''`). It has to do with guaranteeing a contract about what columns exist in the derived table. Why would you ever want to write a query without proper aliases on all columns, even if right now you aren't using one of them?

Comment: @Bohemian: In about 13 different ways (some with length, some without and several that require different number of joins depending on the length of the list): [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Why would I want columns that don't have a proper name? Oh, that's easy to answer! When they are transient and I don't care about their names... just like in this (inner/aliased) query!

Comment: @ypercube I count any query where you have to mention the parameters, or something about the parameters, more than once as "you can't do it". All queries in that other question do this.

Comment: @Bohemian if you don't like using the alias on transient columns, then just drop using the column all together -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/168a1/2

Comment: @bluefeet cool - I like that much more (didn't know the SQL Server supported having without selecting). Re dislike, no other database (I know) requires an alias - it's just code clutter.

Comment: @Bohemian you're getting pretty worked up over something that's relatively insignificant. your initial comment was not constructive at all. fine, you don't like sql server --- thanks for answering the question, though.

Comment: @Bohemian: All except my lucky number 7 :)

Comment: @Bohemian then why are you including it in the output list?

Comment: SQL Server is so hard! It has syntax rules! Time to switch platforms!

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
    declare @1 varchar(10),@2 varchar(10), @3 varchar(10), @sql nvarchar(4000)
set @1='101'
set @2= '103'
set @3= null

set @sql =''
if @1 is not null set @sql = @sql+'
intersect
SELECT [EventType] from SpecimenEvents where [SpecimenID] = ' + @1
if @2 is not null set @sql = @sql+'
intersect
SELECT [EventType] from SpecimenEvents where [SpecimenID] = ' + @2
if @3 is not null set @sql = @sql+'
intersect
SELECT [EventType] from SpecimenEvents where [SpecimenID] = ' + @3
if len(@sql)>13 
begin
set @sql = substring(@sql,14,4000)
execute sp_executesql @sql
end
```

Amit Patel